# Creating auto generated number field as like ObjectID in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase

I have a FGDB with many feature classes. I need a "FeatureID" field it should be auto generated with a sequence number while adding a new feature in Edit session. It is like the existing field "OBJECTID". It is like auto numbering while adding new feature

Comment: Sounds like a job for Attribute Assistant with a GenerateID class. I don't know enough about implementing it to give you a full answer, but hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged your question as ArcGIS Desktop I assume you are open to using ArcGIS Pro.  If so explore the [Attribute Rules](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/overview/an-overview-of-attribute-rules.htm) as a way of auto numbering. *Be aware of the cautions* in the help file as you'll be changing the version of your database and ArcMap users won't be able to access the data.

Comment: I am using Arcmap 10.7

Comment: Here is a useful [blog](http://www.powereng.com/insights/configurable-facility-id-creation-using-the-utility-network/) giving instructions on how to set up a unique incremental ID. But  of cause this is for ArcPro.